# refer to complex expression value in where clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I have a query where I have a complex date expression as one of the columns.

```
SELECT 
    date_column + INTERVAL( complex_jimmy_jam ) DAY AS complex_date_calculation
FROM table
```

I want to refer to that column in the where clause

```
WHERE complex_date_calculation < NOW()
```

But mysql chokes on it.

```
1054: Unknown column 'complex_date_calculation' in 'where clause'
```

One way to do this is to wrap it in a sub-select

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        date_column + INTERVAL( complex_jimmy_jam ) DAY AS complex_date_calculation
    FROM table 
) AS alias
WHERE complex_date_calculation < NOW()
```

Is this the best way?

I could also re-do the calculation in the WHERE clause, but that seems dumb. Why have the database calculate that date twice? Or, will the optimizer store that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I want is `HAVING`:

```
SELECT 
    date_column + INTERVAL( complex_jimmy_jam ) DAY AS complex_date_calculation
FROM table
HAVING complex_date_calculation < NOW()
```

Comment: In my case I had to use both a "where" and also this "having". It's working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

For optimal performance, you should index `date_column` and move the calculation to the other side of the comparator in the where clause, like so:

```
SELECT 
    date_column + INTERVAL( complex_jimmy_jam ) DAY AS complex_date_calculation
FROM table
WHERE date_column < NOW() - INTERVAL( complex_jimmy_jam ) DAY
```

This way the index on `date_column` can be used to satisfy the where clause.